# CKEditor issue in gulp-concat

Tags: angularjs, gulp, ckeditor, gulp-concat

In my `angularjs` application, I'm using [angular-ckeditor](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor)
 directive for CKEditor to get user inputs(Description and comments).

This is my html code to take description;

```
<div ckeditor="options" ng-model="txtDesc" ng-change="descChange()"></div>
```

and for comments;

```
<div ckeditor="options" ng-model="txtComment"></div>
```

And according to [this github article](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor);

> Note : obviously this plugin expects the presence of AngularJS and CKEditor.

This is how I'm referring my JS files;

```
<!-- CK editor -->
<script src="{% static "scripts/angular.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "scripts/angular-ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
```

It is working fine in normal flow. But when I try to concat all scripts file in one file using `gulp-concat`, It throws following errors for both editors;

> The editor instance "editor1" is already attached to the provided element.
>
> The editor instance "editor2" is already attached to the provided element.

This is my JS reference after gulp-concat;

```
<script src="{% static "scripts/scripts.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "scripts/angular-ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
```

`script.js` has angular.js file data with all other js files (Concat all js files in one file). But ckeditor does not get the reference correctly. I tried to concat `angular-ckeditor.js` also wihtin `scripts.js` file, but it results in same. What can I do to get over this error?

Comment: have you tried swapping the order: `angular-ckeditor.js` first,  `ckeditor/ckeditor.js` second?

Comment: yes I did. but no change..